# What are the practical differences between Kafka Topics & Channels?

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, channel, distributed-system, data-stream

Conceptually, I get the difference. As per Kafka [docs](https://kafka.apache.org/intro):

> [...] a topic is similar to a folder in a filesystem, and the events
> are the files in that folder. An example topic name could be
> "payments". Topics in Kafka are always multi-producer and
> multi-subscriber: a topic can have zero, one, or many producers that
> write events to it, as well as zero, one, or many consumers that
> subscribe to these events.

And channels are not Kafka specific but used amongst many streaming services (e.g. [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/channels.html)). Also, Kafka topics can be mapped to channels by Java frameworks like Spring, Quarkus, etc. Furthermore, I see channels being used with Kafka Streams.

These two answers ([ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72806505/what-is-the-difference-between-event-channels-topics) and [ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336439/kafka-stream-vs-topic)) give a theoretical explanation, but I'm looking for something with a use case.

In the context of Apache Kafka, would it be fair to assume that a Kafka channel is a further abstraction of a Kafka topic?

I'd like to learn in a practical engineering sense what the difference is between Kafka Topics & Channels. Thank you!